# Can some one explain what me what this guy did at 4:03 of this tutorial?

Tags: mesh

Hello all I am trying to learn how to sculpt a face. My Blender version is 2.9
I am watching this guy's tutorial on YouTube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqZ-uUJCaAg

At 4:00 he told the viewers to go into sculpting mode. On his screen the ball instantly turned from gray to red.

However on my screen, my ball stayed gray.

Later on, he informed the viewers that he will be using the grab brush.

Between 4:05 and 4:10 he dragged something on the object and a black spot bloomed. What did he do here.

After that, with the brush tool. He dragged the 2nd last horizontal line downwards to form the chin of the face. only the bottom half of the original ball shape moved.

When I attempted this. The entire shape of my ball moved downwards. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The color of the object in sculpt mode (by default) is the result of of a Matcap used to display detail. Older versions used brown clay by default, so I'm guessing that's why he chose that for his setup. You can change it from the Viewport Shadings tab:

[image: Matcap]

The "black circle" I believe is just him resizing the brush. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to place it into size mode then drag with your mouse to resize and click to set that size.

As for your whole model moving, this is likely related to your brush being too big. Resize it using the method above (F), and see if a smaller brush has less of an influence on the rest of the mesh. If not, make sure your mirroring is off.